# How can I mirror/flip a string and/or integer on the y-Axis (vertically) in Python?

Tags: python, string, integer, flip, mirroring

I'm writing a GUI in Python (Tkinter) which will be used as a Head Up Display in a car. Unfortunately I didn't find any solution to mirror the whole displayed Screen so I try to mirror the words and numbers. When I tried to look it up everybody just takes 'hallo' and gets 'ollah'. But I try to even display the letters like you would get them when you mirror them vertically.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using PIL Images? You can transpose these:

```py
import Tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

pil_image = Image.open(...)
flipped_pil_image = pil_image.transpose(Image.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I came through some posts talking about it but it didn´t really work for me because the pictures I use are symetrical and I only need to transpose text and numbers. Currently I´m trying to programm a seven segment number output to achieve my goal. If you have any other solution to flip text or numbers I´d highly appreciate it.